# Is it possible to smooth my Unity3D progress bar?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created a simple GUI progress bar that starts at 0px and expands to 640px.  It works great, but appears a little jumpy.  I can live with it, but if I can make it appear smoother, that would be ideal.

Any suggestions?

```
IEnumerator Timer() {

    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

    while (true) {

        float tick = (float)DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds;

        Debug.Log("TimeInSeconds: " + (int)tick);

        rawImageRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(tick / 60f * 640f, 10f); 

        if (tick > 60f) {
            break;
        }

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As per suggestions, I've tried the following and the effect is identical.

```
rawImageRectTransform.sizeDelta = Vector2.Lerp(new Vector2(0, 10f), new Vector2(640f, 10f), tick/60f);
```

I've also tried it this way:

```
rawImageRectTransform.sizeDelta = Vector2.Lerp(new Vector2(0, 10f), new Vector2(640f, 10f), Time.fixedTime/60f);
```

And the effect is the same, however the progress bar is no loger sync'd to the `DateTime.TotalSeconds` (ie. `tick`) value, so this isn't going to work.

Comment: put it in FixUpdate() as opposed to calling coroutines.

Comment: Not sure how that will help, since it's all based on time in seconds.

Comment: I would use a lerp or a slerp, or use the smoothed deltaTime instead of that date you are using now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Vector3.lerp()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) or [Vector2.lerp()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Lerp.html) in a `FixedUpdate()` it will make sure *your requirement* gets called fixed number of times per second still it might also work with co-routine without much visual irregulaties.

```
// for a 3d system
public static Vector3 Lerp(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, float t);

// for a 2d system
public static Vector2 Lerp(Vector2 from, Vector2 to, float t);
```

Comment: sizeDelta is width and height property assigned via a Vector2.  I'm not certain Lerp will work in this instance.

Comment: @JasonCaldwell there is a `vector2.lerp` as well, I'll update the answer!

Comment: Ok, I think I can see how this could be used -- I'll play with it and post back here.

Comment: Well, running into a snag.  Any chance you could provide an example based on my code?

Comment: @JasonCaldwell I did not try to post any examples as unity API has a nice example. did you try http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html ?
If it does not work out I'll update my answer to suit your requirements

Comment: Ok, tried it, but didn't work.  Is there something I may be missing?  (I've updated my question above to reflect what I tried).

Comment: Are you calling it inside a `FixedUpdate()` ?  `rawImageRectTransform.sizeDelta = Vector2.Lerp(new Vector2(0, 10f), new Vector2(640f, 10f), tick/60f);` looks fine too.. BTW did you debug and check whether `tick/60f` value goes `0.0` to `1.0` ?

Comment: Not seeing how `FixedUpdate` will smooth the calculation of `(tick/60f) * 640` or just `tick/60f`.  Using a CoRoutine is ideal instead of throwing stuff in `Update` or `FixedUpdate` where I'd have to then play w/ `boolean` values to start and stop stuff.  To your 2nd question: `1/60 = 0.0166, 2/60 = 0.0333 .... 50/60 = 0.8333, 60/60 = 1.0`